# CSS create grid with element take 1,5 space if container empty

Tags: css, css-grid

I have container like this :

[image]

At the moment there is an empty case after element 5. So I would like to center the elements of the second line :

[image]

For the code i've already done :

```
      .country-grid
        display: grid
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(320px, 1fr))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the exact use case and how many grid items you are expecting. If you know you are always going to have 5 items, you could just set a specific number of columns and offset the 4th item like so:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
}
```

If the layout could have any number of items and you are looking at a more fluid approach when it comes to wrapping, then I'd suggest using [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) for this as it's a lot simpler for setting up alignment like this:

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  min-width: 320px;
}
```